# SQL Query to retrieve the last records till the quantity purchased reaches the total quantity in stock

Tags: sql

I have a table that have the ItemCode and Quantity in stock and another table that contains the purchases.

I want a query to get the Quantity in stock (ex. Qty = 5) and to take the purchase table to get the purchase invoices by descending order and take the Item Prices.
The Query has to keep retrieving records from the Purchase table according to the Quantity till we reach sum of Quantity in stock = 5.
ex.

```
**Purchase No   ItemCode   Qty   Cost Price**

    2             123       2       100
    3             123       10      105 
    6             123       2       100 
    8             123       1        90
    9             123       2       120
```

### ---------------------------------------------

```
**ItemCode     Qty in Stock**

    123             5
```

### --------------------------------------------

In this example I want the query to retrieve for me the last 3 invoices (9,8 and 6) because the Qty (2+1+2 = 5)

Is there any suggestion .
Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Is that MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

This script should do the job.

```
/* SQL SCRIPT BEGIN */


create table #tmp (PurchaseNo int, ItemCode int, Qty int)


insert into #tmp (PurchaseNo, ItemCode, Qty)


select 

p1.PurchaseNo, p1.ItemCode, sum(t.Qty) as Qty

from

Purchases p1

join 

(

select 
p2.PurchaseNo, 
p2.ItemCode, p2.Qty 
from
Purchases p2

) t on p1.PurchaseNo <= t.PurchaseNo and p1.ItemCode = t.ItemCode

group by p1.PurchaseNo, p1.ItemCode

order by p1.ItemCode, sum(t.Qty) asc




select * From #tmp
where
ItemCode = 123 
and
Qty < 5 
union
select top 1 * From #tmp
where
ItemCode = 123 
and
Qty >= 5 
order by PurchaseNo desc

drop table #tmp

/* SQL SCRIPT END */
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hi This can be the solution : 
Here I have Used Result Table which will store the result.**
I have used three tables **Purchage**(PurchageNo,ItemCode,Qty) , **Stock**(ItemCode,QtyInStock) and **result**(PurchageNo).
Full Workable Code is Here:

```
DECLARE @ItemCode int; 
DECLARE @AvailableQty int; 
SET @ItemCode = 123 ; 
SET @AvailableQty = (select QtyInStock from Stock where ItemCode = @ItemCode); 
SELECT 
    RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PurchageNo),*   
INTO #PurchageTemp
FROM Purchage

DECLARE @MaxRownum INT;
SET @MaxRownum = (select COUNT(*)from #PurchageTemp);

DECLARE @Iter INT;
SET @Iter = 1;
DECLARE @QtySum int=0; 
DECLARE @QtySumTemp int=0; 
DECLARE @CurrentItem int; 
WHILE (@Iter <= @MaxRownum and @QtySum <= @AvailableQty)
BEGIN
set @QtySumTemp=@QtySum;
set @QtySumTemp = @QtySumTemp + (SELECT Qty FROM #PurchageTemp WHERE RowNum = @Iter and ItemCode=@ItemCode);
IF @QtySumTemp <= @AvailableQty 
BEGIN
set @QtySum=@QtySumTemp;
  set @CurrentItem= (SELECT PurchageNo FROM #PurchageTemp WHERE RowNum = @Iter and ItemCode=@ItemCode);
              insert into [Result] values (@CurrentItem);
END
              SET @Iter = @Iter + 1
END
DROP TABLE #PurchageTemp
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, ive been trying from 2 hours to apply your code but i failed :( . is it possible if u may write it again according to my tables names as per the attached picture

Comment: The PrintScreen Snaps are not clear to me but the two tables that u have given to me at the top -one with (**Purchase No  , ItemCode ,  Qty  , Cost Price**) I called it as "Purchage" table and another with (**ItemCode   ,  Qty in Stock**) I called it as "Stock" table . and to store result I have used another table "result" that u have to create with a column "PurchageNo".All columns in all tables are of "int" type.  In code we have "#PurchageTemp" , this is tem table no need to wory about this...